# How to simply map cells from one csv "matrix" to another csv matrix with pandas data frames preserving row/column order

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I want to create a csv file as a copy one csv to another replacing values in the original also mapping columns with different "header name keys" from another file and replacing columns in the origial. Each file has the same number of rows. The row order needs to be maintained from input to output, and the column order needs to be maintained in the order of the original file being altered. in sort of C++ java like pseudo code I want to do:

```
newValues = pandas.read_csv('newValues.csv')
sourceMatrix = pandas.read_csv('sourceFile.csv')

# note index is positional from row 0 to max

for( rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < rowCount; ++rowIndex) {
   newRow = newValues.rows[rowIndex];
   destRow = sourceMatrix.rows[rowIndex];
   # modify original row columns "sparsely" with other "newValues" columns
   destRow['destKey1'] = newValues['sourceKey1'] 
   ...
   sourceMatrix.rows[rowIndex] = destRow # replace original row with changed row
}

# write output of altered source 
sourceMatrix.to_csv('outputFile.csv')
```

Lots of bits and pieces out there in partial and barely described contexts but not easy to grok how to do the above when everything is dynamic lookup and potentially not preserving key/value order. In this case data type is not relevant just whether strings or not strings in the fields.

Answer (score 0):

Ok - man official Pandas docs are poor.

This is a pretty good one when you don't know the system already.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python_pandas

Anyway here is a first pass that works.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import os
import sys
import pandas as pd

fileToMapTo = 'SourceValues.csv'
fileToCorrectFrom = './correctedValues.csv'
outputFile = 'SourceValues-corrected.csv'


#  read in the source files
print("mapping \"" + fileToCorrectFrom + "\" over " + fileToMapTo);

try:
    subject_df = pd.read_csv(fileToMapTo) # load with default positional index
    fixer_df = pd.read_csv(fileToCorrectFrom) # load with default positional index
except:
    sys.err.write("Pandas Unable to load: \"" + fileToValidate + "\"\n")
    sys.exit(1)

# create new frame with same column headers as source frame (sets 'x' size of columns)
# and same "index" ( sets Y size of matrix and fills with empty rows )
output_df = pd.DataFrame( index = subject_df.index, columns = subject_df.columns.values );

#iterate over rows (In index order)
for index, row in subject_df.iterrows():
    row['AccNumber'] = 1234  # replace a value for a specific column
    output_df.iloc[index] = row  # set item in output to item in (copy of) input

#write output .csv file from output data frame

# create output folder for results if not present
outputDir = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(outputFile, os.pardir))
if not os.path.isdir(outputDir):
    os.makedirs(outputDir)

print("writing mapped file to: \"" + outputFile + "\"")

# write without (generated integer, ordered) index names
output_df.to_csv(outputFile, index=False)
```